# What is the original quote of “To be calm is the highest achievement of the self"?

Tags: translation, classical-chinese, proverb, buddhism

This is allegedly a "Zen proverb":

> “To be calm is the highest achievement of the self”

I tried to look for it by searching on Google, but I could not find the original. What is the original text of this translated quote?

Comment: "保持镇定是自我的最高成就"? I haven't seen this proverb before, just translate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To be calm is the highest achievement of the self.---Yogi Bhajan.

Note that based on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbhajan_Singh_Khalsa)

> 'Yogi Bhajan was born on August 26, 1929 into a Sikh family in Kot Harkarn, Gujranwala district, in the province of Punjab (now in Pakistan)'.

Firstly, he is not Chinese, also he don't speak Chinese, the original text certainly not in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

“宁静致远” 这个词也许能表达您那句话的意思。
只有心灵的宁静，才能专注、深入思考、心胸开阔、正确行动，需要持续提升自我的修养，从而成就自我。